# How do you document programs that accesses a database using SQL?

Tags: mysql

How do you document programs that accesses a database using SQL? 
A detailed explaination can help me

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because question is about documentation not about a programming issue.https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: to add to @P.Salmon 's comment not to mention primarily opinion-based as the only "standard" are comment annotations in the form of `@annotation` like `@param`, `@return` .. But  comment annotations are also is depending on the used programming language/frameworks even which you use or Documentor tool to create HTML pages like [phpDocumentor](https://www.phpdoc.org/) .. Still the best documention in mine opinion is self describing code to give a example when you read `database->getUserById(id)` or `database->getUsers()` you know directly what it does..